# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) in Eclipse

Tags: java, syntax-error

So I'm having troubles with my program here. I'm supposed to write a program that calls for the Accelerate / Brake methods in a car. I'm getting the Syntax error in the first half of the code, but the second half is marked as correct.

`Car` class:

```
public class Car {
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(String m, int year) {
        yearModel = year;
        make = m;
        speed = 0;
    }

    // Declare mutators (methods).

    // Declare accessors (methods).
    public int getModel() { // Model year of car.
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setModel(int year) {
        yearModel = year;
    }

    public void setMake(String carMake) {
        make = carMake;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int s) { // Incorrect??? Possible outSpeed = speed;
        speed = s;          // Not sure if correct; should be "0" | or equal to "carSpeed"
    }

    public void accelerateSpeed() {
        speed += 5;
        // Each call will increase by 5.
    }

    public void brakeSpeed() {
        speed -= 5;
        // Each call will decrease by 5.
    }
}
```

`CarResults` class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class CarResults {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input, carMake;
        int model, yearModel, year, s;

        Car myCar = new Car("Car", 2011);

        // Retrieve car's Make & Model.
        carMake = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the Make of your car? ");
        myCar.setMake(carMake);

        year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the Model Year of your car? "));
        myCar.setModel(year);

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your car's speed: ");
        s = Integer.parseInt(input);
        myCar.setSpeed(s);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            myCar.accelerateSpeed();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The " + " " + myCar.getModel() + " " + myCar.getMake() +
                " is gradually accelerating. ");

            // Apply acceleration.
            System.out.println("Your current speed is: " + myCar.getSpeed());
        }

        // Begin applying brakes.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t>>> Now, let's get the results for applying the brakes... ");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            myCar.brakeSpeed();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("[Braking] Your" + " " + myCar.getModel() + " " + myCar.getMake() + " is now traveling at: ");

            // Apply brakes.

            System.out.println("Now your speed is: " + myCar.getSpeed());
        }

        // End the program.
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about what error you are getting? Often the error message tells you exactly what is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with this. I was able to compile and run this just fine.  Try compiling on your command line with

```
javac CarResults.java Car.java
```

and then run it with

```
java CarResults
```

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class Car, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application                                                    The other error is now gone, this is the new one that shows up. ^

Comment: I added the main method definition but it keeps saying it's not found. This is for car class.

Comment: Make sure you are typing in the commands exactly as I have them.  If you do `java Car` instead of `java CarResults` you would get the error you described.